Publish new Azure Static Web Apps from Data API Builder
Trying to set up our first Static Web App in Azure, connecting it to our SQL Server in Azure, but struggling to get off the ground.  When I add the "Database Connection (preview)" environment, it says

The database connection configuration file is missing from your repository.

In the Azure portal, we have 3 resources: SQL server, SQL database, and Static Web App.
I've created a dab-config.json, a SWA-4.database.config.json, and a staticwebapp.database.config.json.  All 3 files are in my GitHub repository's root level.  3, because it's unclear to my untrained brain if the file prefix needs to match my Static Web App name, if it should just be staticwebapp., or if it should be dab-config.

All 3 JSON files have the same content
{
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/download/v1.2.14/dab.draft.schema.json",
  "data-source": {
    "database-type": "mssql",
    "connection-string": "Server=tcp:REMOVED,1433;Initial Catalog=REMOVED;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=REMOVED;Password=REMOVED;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
    "options": {
      "set-session-context": false
    }
  },
  "runtime": {
    "rest": {
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/api",
      "request-body-strict": true
    },
    "graphql": {
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/graphql",
      "allow-introspection": true
    },
    "host": {
      "cors": {
        "origins": [],
        "allow-credentials": false
      },
      "authentication": {
        "provider": "StaticWebApps"
      },
      "mode": "production"
    }
  },
 "entities": {
........ continued ..............

When I look at my GitHub Actions… one of the Static Web Apps workflows is successful, but the other two, Update dab-config.json and "ci: add Azure Static Web Apps workflow file" both give the same error

The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest. Reason: No matching Static Web App was found or the api key was invalid."


Index.html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
    </head>


<button  id="list"  onclick="list()">List</button>

</html>

script.js
async  function  list() {

    const  response = await  fetch('/data-api/rest/VirtuousAI_Matches');
    
    const  data = await  response.json();
    
    console.table(data.value);
}

At this point I'm completely unsure of which step I've messed up.   Any help is appreciated

Actually we don't ask people to share their repos on this site. Questions need to be standalone and clear in their own right.

@adam  the database connection in the staticwebapp.database.config.json 

@dab use Static Web Apps CLI to generate a dab configuration file by running
swa db init --database-type mssql in local and use dab add Item -c "staticwebapp.database.config.json" --source dbo.ShoppingItems --permissions "anonymous:*" . SO you see Data API will be accessed via <WEB APP URL>/data-api/rest/<ENTITY>

@adam Refer to this doc for staticwebapp.database.config.json configuration.

Below are steps to Publish Azure Static Web Apps with Data API Builder.After writing code for list, get, update, create, and delete in index.html, use the following:
<button  id="list"  onclick="list()">List</button>

async  function  list() {

const  response = await  fetch('/data-api/rest/Person');

const  data = await  response.json();

console.table(data.value);

}

In cmd install the Static Web Apps CLI using the command:
npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli .

I referred to this documentation for connecting to a database with Azure Static Web  Apps.

Then use the command swa db init --database-type mssql to initialize a database connection for your Azure Static Web App project with a Microsoft SQL Server database.
Open the staticwebapp.database.config.json file and add the following content:
{
  "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/latest/download/dab.draft.schema.json",
  "data-source": {
    "database-type": "mssql",
    "options": {
      "set-session-context": false
    },
    "connection-string": "Server=tcp:<your_server>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<your_db>;User ID=<your_user>;Password=<your_password>;Encrypt=true;"
  },
  "runtime": {
    "rest": {
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/rest"
    },
    "graphql": {
      "allow-introspection": true,
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "/graphql"
    },
    "host": {
      "mode": "production",
      "cors": {
        "origins": ["*"],
        "allow-credentials": false
      },
      "authentication": {
        "provider": "StaticWebApps"
      }
    }
  },
  "entities": {
    "Person": {
      "source": "dbo.MyTestPersonTable",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "actions": ["*"],
          "role": "anonymous"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


I referred to thislink for configuring Azure Static Web Apps and this documentation for swa-cli.config.json.
Use the command swa init to create a swa-cli.config.json file like the following:
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",
  "configurations": {
    "new-folder-(6)": {
      "appLocation": "scr\\public",
      "outputLocation": ".",
      "dataApiLocation": "swa-db-connections",
      "appDevserverUrl": "http://localhost:4280"
    }
  }
}


Create    staticwebapp.config.json in the main and add staticwebapp.config.json with the following content:

{
    "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "/index.html",
      "exclude": [
        "/api/*",
        "/static/*"
      ]
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "route": "/api/*",
        "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
      },
      {
        "route": "/admin",
        "allowedRoles": ["admin"]
      },
      {
        "route": "/",
        "rewrite": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "route": "/static/*",
        "headers": {
          "cache-control": "max-age=31536000"
        }
      }
    ],
    "responseOverrides": {
      "404": {
        "rewrite": "/404.html"
      },
      "403": {
        "rewrite": "/403.html"
      }
    },
    "globalHeaders": {
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload",
      "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; connect-src 'self'; frame-src 'none';"
    },
    "platform": {
      "apiRuntime": "node:18"
    },
    "networking": {
      "allowedIpRanges": [
        "0.0.0.0/0"
      ]
    }
  }

Create the dbo.MyTestPersonTable in Azure SQL .Allow public network access and allow azure service and sevices to acess the service. Then Start the app locally using:
swa start ./scr/public --data-api-location swa-db-connections 

If you encounter firewall issues during swa start, add the necessary firewall rules in SQL Server.

Push the code, .env, staticwebapp.config.json, swa-cli.config.json, and staticwebapp.database.config.json to GitHub.

Modify the GitHub YAML configuration file as follows, replace app_location according to your folder structure:
 app_location: "./scr/public" 
 api_location: ""
 output_location: "." 


Go to the Database connection in Static Web Apps => link the existing database, and view the app in the browser.

Output:



Thank you so much for all the detail!!! I feel like I'm nearly there.    When I run the step of "swa start ......." , after the index.html page loads, then I execute the javascript:
GET, I'm receiving a 404.  Same with when I manually navigate to the URL:
http://localhost:4280/data-api/rest/myEntityNameHere

Please share your index.html in above questions.

original post (at the bottom) has been updated now with index & javascript

While using separate files for the index and JavaScript, I encountered the same error. To resolve this, I combined both files into a single index.html file. You can refer to my GitHub repository for a sample index.html file.
